Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, mkdir 'cdk.out/ when adding a lambda stage to my cdk pipeline
I've got a cdk pipeline and want to add my lambda stage, however getting this error below.
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError:        
Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, mkdir 'cdk.out

class LambdaStage(Stage):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        ProtectionGroupStage(
            self,
            'ProtectionGroupStage',
            **kwargs,

        )
class PipelineStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        pipeline_source = pipelines.CodePipelineSource.connection(xxxx)

        pipeline = pipelines.CodePipeline(
            self,
            "ShieldAdvancedPipeline",
            synth=pipelines.ShellStep(
                "Synth",
            input=pipeline_source,
            commands=[
                "npm install -g aws-cdk",
                "pip install poetry==1.8.2",
                "cdk synth"
                ],
            ),
        )
        
        deploy = LambdaStage(self, "Deploy")
        deploy_stage = pipeline.add_stage(deploy)

I just want to add my lambda stage to be added to my cdk pipeline i've created.
Lambda code below which gets cloudfront distributions which I will be storing into an s3 bucket to use later in my pipeline
def get_unprotected_arns(filter_substring, s3_bucket_name, s3_object_key):
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
        aws_session_token=os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN']
    )
    client = session.boto3.client('cloudfront')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_distributions')
    arns = []

    for page in paginator.paginate():
        for distribution in page['DitributionList']['Items']:
            if any(filter_substring in domain for domain in distribution['Aliases']['Items']):                
                arn = distribution['ARN']
                arns.append(arn)

    unprotected_arns = [arn for arn in arns if arn not in list_existing_protections(session)]

    s3_client = session.client('s3')
    s3_client.put(
        Bucket=s3_bucket_name,
        Key=s3_object_key,
        Body=json.dumps(unprotected_arns)
    )
    return unprotected_arns

